# Unable to register endpoint startup with ServiceControl

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I'm doing a version 0.0.1 implementation of a host based Endpoint, which has worked just fine until I got errors complaining about:

> non-Unicode headers *something something* ...

At transport database level.

*Sadly that didn't get logged, so I don't have the exact message.*

As I didn't have that before, I removed my localdb and recreated it blank. I ran the endpoint again and now I get these notifications:

**Unable to register endpoint startup with ServiceControl**

```
2017-08-24 10:03:48.743 | Warn | ServiceControl.Features.Heartbeats | Unable to register endpoint startup with ServiceControl. Going to reattempt registration after 00:01:00.
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to [ServiceBusTransport].[dbo].[Particular.ServiceControl.Dev] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'ServiceBusTransport.dbo.Particular.ServiceControl.Dev'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

**Unable to send heartbeat to ServiceControl**

```
2017-08-24 10:03:58.757 | Warn | ServiceControl.Features.Heartbeats | Unable to send heartbeat to ServiceControl.
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to [ServiceBusTransport].[dbo].[Particular.ServiceControl.Dev] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'ServiceBusTransport.dbo.Particular.ServiceControl.Dev'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

> I've got no clue what I changed to cause this, any idea?

I do know that `Particular.ServiceControl.Dev` is the name of my ServiceControl Queue. It feels like the matching table wasn't created, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, we don't have ServiceControl set up at dev level. And since I removed the `ServiceBusTransport` database in it's entirity, the `Particular.ServiceControl.Dev` wasn't being created.

After creating it manually using this query, it worked again:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Particular.ServiceControl.Dev](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CorrelationId] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ReplyToAddress] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Recoverable] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Expires] [datetime] NULL,
    [Headers] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Body] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [RowVersion] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: With the ServiceControl Management utility you can also delete and recreate this.

Comment: Yes, but that's not active locally :).